# proxy authorization on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, http, proxy, authorization, nsurlconnection

Have such a problem, hope you'll help me.. Can't find anywhere. Here is the code i'm using:

```
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someServer.com/Login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
[request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ACCEPT"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];

NSData *data = [encodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

URLLoader *loader = [URLLoader loaderWithRequest:request];
```

When I want to acces to the server http://someServer.com/Login from browser on computer all ok.

When I tryied to acces the same server from safary on iPhone simulator - authorization window appears after authorization all was OK.

But when I perform this request in a program way on iPhone simulator, code sample I have posted. Next error appears:

```
The following error was encountered:
Cache Access Denied.

Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:
   http://someserver.com/Login
from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
```

How can I solve this problem?? Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that you need to send the authentication credentials when you make the call. 
Try to use `NSURLConnection` class to make the call, set the delegate and implement the following method

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"ABC"
                                                 password:@"XYZ"
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    } else {

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        // inform the user that the user name and password
        // in the preferences are incorrect
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx, I just added this server to the list to use it without proxy.

Comment: is there any way by which authentication can be done for both proxy and the main website using the synchronous method ?